# How do I prefill a formview textbox in insert mode if the text property is already set to bind?

Tags: c#

I have a formview control that I use to upload data to an attached gridview controller. At the top of my gridview I use a asp:linkbutton to set my formview to insert mode with

```
    FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert);
```

Here is my textbox in the insert template of the formview:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="Date_Position_AvailableTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Position_Available") %>' />
```

Here is my code in the formLoad. this is where I believe I am prefilling the value of the textbox control:

```
     if (!IsPostBack)  
        {  
            FillDefaultVaueInFormView();  
        }
```

And finally here is my FillDefaultVaueInFormView(); function.

```
    public void FillDefaultVaueInFormView()
    {

        if (FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
        {

            TextBox txtPositionAvailable = FormView1.FindControl("Date_Position_AvailableTextBox") as TextBox;
            if (txtPositionAvailable != null)
            {
                txtPositionAvailable.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            }
        }
    }
```

When I enter the Insert Mode the field is Blank. What am I doing wrong here?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your `FillDefaultValueInFormView()` to occur right after you set the FormView to Insert mode.  When you attempt to fill the fields at the form load, the textboxes don't exist (when you're not in insert or edit mode, the "textboxes" are actually labels).  This is causing your `if` statement to come back false and thus is not filling the values.

Comment: Are you saying to add `FillDefaultValueInFormView()` to the Linkbutton's Click command. When I do that I still get blank values

Comment: In my projects, I have also put it in the `FormView_DataBound` method.  You can wrap your command in an if block like this `if(FormView.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)` to make sure it fires only after you've set it to insert mode.  You may want to put a breakpoint at or inside the if to make sure your process is even running.  It's not uncommon to have your code somewhere you think is running but then find out that event is never triggered.

Comment: I tried that earlier and it did not work...working now though...thanks guys!

Comment: I am not finding any documentation on the usage of FillDefaultValueInFormView().  I'm working with a similar issue to the one posted here and this sounds like it would work if I could just see the syntax for using it.